# calling service method running on separate thread from another thread in jhipster

Tags: jhipster

i have created a jhipster app, in this app I'm running a separate thread for tcp connection. In this thread I'm calling a service of the app running. At the service call line it's throwing exception :
Exception in thread : java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Show some code if you want some help in particular how do you inject your service into your thread code.

Comment: in jhipster main app i'm starting a thread while this thread is running ,i want  to call a service which is there in jhipster . for that I injected service into that class of thread. Separate thread I'm running is not able to call service method in jhipster.

Comment: How did you start /create your thread?